# Create Singleton class and restrict to two objects in java?(Like double )

Tags: java

I have created one Singleton with private constructor and public static method. Now my requirement is, need to create two objects for same class.

Comment: Then that class is not a singleton at all.

Comment: keep a counter and increase it everytime an object is created and then limit this counter's value to 2 or 3 as desired

Comment: Please read the "How to ask a good question" page (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I'm really not seeing much evidence of research you have done thus far on this problem, or any sample code that isn't doing what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you are gonna retain more than one instance of the class then you are actually not using Singleton pattern (as pointed out by [ANS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1927832/ans)).

Anyway your question sounds like you need multiple yet limited number of instances of a class. In that case, Object Pool pattern can be useful for you. Please find the wiki link below for your reference (sample java code snippet also found in the same wiki page):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create two instances of a class, then what's the point of creating a singleton class?

> Singleton pattern restricts the instantiation of a class and ensures that only one instance of the class exists in the java virtual machine.

If you want only two objects to be created, have a static counter to check the number of objects created.. But your class will cease to be singleton.